# Javascript function transfomr my value in undefined. Me and my teacher does'nt understand why

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I'm here today because i've an error I (and my teacher) don't understand in javascript.

The following code is just an factorial by a function (forced to do it with function). But my value is changed in undefined when return.

```js
var test;
do {
  var result = parseInt(prompt("Un chiffre supérieur à 1"));
} while (isNaN(result) || result < 2);
// Just asking for a number > à 1 it work //

test = facto(result, 1);
console.log(test);
// The test variable was used to try to understand the bug //

function facto(chiffre, fact) {
  // Function for the factorial //

  fact = fact * chiffre;
  // fact was defined as 1 for the first entry, for others it's gonna be his last  result //`
  console.log(fact);
  chiffre = chiffre - 1;
  // We decrase chiffre by one for the next passage //


  if (chiffre == 1) {
    // if chiffre = 1, we don't need to do other passage, so we return value 
    console.log(fact);
    return fact;
    // the result is correct, it's a number. However it return undefined //
  } else {
    // if chiffre > 1, we continue the math by coming again in the function //
    console.log(chiffre);
    facto(chiffre, fact);
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it return undefined. Could someone explain me ?
Also, the function work if it go only one time in the function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your recursive call is missing `return`. You should have `return facto(chiffre, fact);` at the end there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the recursive call, else the first call of `facto` will never encounter a `return` statement, resulting in that first call (by default) returning `undefined`. Change to `return facto(chiffre, fact);`:

```js
var test;
do {
  var result = parseInt(prompt("Un chiffre supérieur à 1"));
} while (isNaN(result) || result < 2);
test = facto(result, 1);
console.log(test);

function facto(chiffre, fact) {
  fact = fact * chiffre;
  chiffre = chiffre - 1;
  if (chiffre == 1) {
    return fact;
  } else {
    return facto(chiffre, fact);
  }
}
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you're a little bit too absolute with your words. Teachers aren't geniuses and sometimes don't notice simple things that we notice. It's only human.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it.
And yeah, teacher are human too and can miss things like we do ;) !